# Faker mutually deterministic randomness across 2 or more systems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, faker

In my rails project, I've set `Faker::Config.random = Random.new(77)`, following the [guide](https://github.com/stympy/faker#deterministic-random). While the randomness is the same every time for me on my computer and my peer's individually, the randomness is not mutually the same.

For instance, the randomness generated by `Faker::Number.number(1)` on my computer is 4, 5, 6; and on my peer's computer is 1, 2, 3. All I'm trying to achieve is 4, 5, 6 on all the machines using the same seed.

How can I achieve this? If it can't be done using that, I'd really appreciate someone suggesting me a workaround.

**EDIT**- The problem is not limited to numbers only. The set of strings and other variables being used to generate randomness is different as well, along with any other data type.

Comment: Doesn't `Faker::Number.within(4..6)` fulfil what you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: @RahulSharma Hi Rahul. I've edited the question. Hopefully, that clears out what I'm trying to convey. The problem is that the set being used for randomness is different on both computers. 1, 2, 3 and 4, 5, 6 were just used as examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I didn't run pull the faker related changes on the remote machine. Everything works like a charm!